# Can a matrix have multiple sets of eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I tried calculating eigenvalues of matrix $A$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-2000&-1500000&-375000000&-62500000000\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

They turned out to be imaginary as below. But when i calculate manually det(SI-A)=0 i get (s+500)(s+500)(s+500)(s+500)=0 which is very obvious that roots are -500,-500,-500,-500 and so are eigen values. What mistake did i do here?
[image]

Comment: The imaginary values are correct, the det gives us $s^4+2000 s^3+1500000 s^2+375000000 s+62500000000$, which gives the same $4$ roots as the imaginary values.

Answer (score 1):

When you compute the determinant of $sI-A$ you should get (expanding down the leftmost column)

\begin{align*}
\text{det}(sI-A)&=(s+2000)\left|\begin{matrix}s&0 & 0  \\ -1 & s & 0 \\0 & -1 & s\end{matrix}\right| -(-1) \left|\begin{matrix}1500000&375000000 & 62500000000  \\ -1 & s & 0 \\0 & -1 & s\end{matrix} \right|\\
&=(s+2000)(s^3)+ 1500000s^2-(-1)(375000000s+62500000000)\\
&=s^4+2000s^3 + 1500000s^2 +375000000s+62500000000.
\end{align*}
This does indeed have the four imaginary roots you posted: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=s%5E4%2B2000s%5E3+%2B+1500000s%5E2+%2B375000000s%2B62500000000%3D0

Comment: But if you plug in -500 this will satisy. so is -500 an eigen value?

Comment: $-500$ does not satisfy this. Check your computations again.

Comment: Hi sorry, i was using this some calculation somewhere in the expansion of (s+r1)(s+r2)(s+r3)(s+r4) i missed the term r1*r2*r4 for the coeffficinets of s. so is the error!!

Answer (score 0):

$$(x-500)^4=x^4+2000x^3+1500000x^2+\color{red}{500Mx}+62500M$$
$$det(A-xI)=x^4+2000x^3+1500000x^2+\color{red}{375Mx}+62500M$$
(M=million)

Comment: Also, this matrix is extremely [ill-conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number), so rounding errors get dramatically amplified when you calculate with it.

Comment: Hi sorry, i was using this some calculation somewhere in the expansion of (s+r1)(s+r2)(s+r3)(s+r4) i missed the term r1*r2*r4 for the coeffficinets of s. so is the error!!

Comment: By the way this matrix is in Control Canonical( one of the applications in State feedback and estimation) form so can't do much about the way it is.